# How to connect my iphone to PC and edit my contacts and other things like I can do with my Nokia phone?

Tags: iphone

How to connect my iPhone to PC and edit my contacts and other things like I can do with my [Nokia phone](http://www.nokia.co.in/support/download-software/nokia-pc-suites)?

Comment: There are (too) many things other phones can do that iPhone can't. The most annoying ones are also the most common, such as easily and freely transferring files (or even photos), SMS, Notes, Call History... At least contacts you can do with freaking iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

You can in iTunes define which online Service or PC program you want to use.

In the [iPhone User Guide](http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/iPhone_User_Guide.pdf) on page 55, are the below written.

> **Info Pane**
>
> The Info pane lets you
>   configure the sync settings for your
>   contacts, calendars, email accounts,
>   and web browser.
>
> - Contacts
>
>   Sync contacts with applications such as Mac
>     OS X Address Book, Yahoo! Address
>     Book, and Google Contacts on a Mac, **or
>     with Yahoo! Address Book, Google
>     Contacts, Windows Address Book
>     (Outlook Express), Windows Contacts
>     (Vista and Windows 7), or Microsoft
>     Outlook 2003, 2007, or 2010 on a PC.**
>     (On a Mac, you can sync contacts with
>     multiple applications. On a PC, you
>     can sync contacts with one application
>     at a time.)
>
>   If you sync with Yahoo!
>     Address Book, you only need to click
>     Configure to enter your new login
>     information when you change your
>     Yahoo! ID or password after you’ve set
>     up syncing.

Comment: I also can send , edit my SMS from nokia using Nokia software from myPC  , is it possible from iphone?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of - maybe if you jailbreak your iPhone, but I don't know about this issue.

Comment: A quick Google search gave me this link: http://www.iphonesmstransfer.com/how-to-edit-iphone-sms-messages-in-computer.html - but not a free program. And this: http://osxdaily.com/2010/07/08/read-iphone-sms-backup/

Answer (score 0):

I use iCloud to sync the Contacts from my iPhone.  I can then view and edit changes Contacts from the iCloud site on any PC.

FYI, an iPhone connected iTunes on a Mac can sync contacts with the Mac's Address Book.